# How to increase popup width in python folium?

Tags: python, folium

I am iterating through my dataframe, using each value in each column to add in popup. However width of popup is too small therefore one value is shown in multiple rows.

this is what my code looks like:

```
c = folium.Map(
    location=[12.323, 146.029326],
    zoom_start=14
)
for row in df.itertuples():
    name = getattr(row, "name")
    age  = getattr(row, "age")
    folium.Marker(
        location = location,
        popup=folium.Popup(f"""name= {name} <br>
                               age = {age} <br>
                            """),
        icon=plugins.BeautifyIcon(
            border_color = color,
            border_width = 2,
            text_color   = 'black'
        )
    ).add_to(c)
```

I want enough space for each column value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `max_width` for the `Popup` object. You can specify a number that depends on the number of caracters in the line of the name like this :

```
popup=folium.Popup(f"""name= {name} <br>
                       age = {age} <br>
                    """, max_width=len(f"name= {name}")*20),
```